# How to curve the div from bottom with image background

Tags: html, css, svg

[image][image]
Is it possible to add the bottom curved using HTML CSS so we don't ned to crop the image like this? The main purpose of this is to allow image curved automatically like that,
I tried to add border-radius but it won't work. Any help?

I think we need to use the SVG? I am not sure.

Comment: Take a look at [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Comment: @JordiNebot I think this is what I am looking for, Do you have any experience with clip-path?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) requirements you could use `clip-path` and `circle`.

```css
.clip {
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: circle(100% at 50% -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="clip">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/500x350" alt="">
</div>
```

`circle(100% at 50% -50%)` defines a circle whose radius is `100%` (of container's width) positioned at the point of coordinates `x = 50%` `y = -50%` on the container's coordinate system. Adjust those parameters to fit your needs (depending on the real size of your container and image).

Comment: Can we us it with a background image as well?

Comment: Sure @Bilal, anything within the target div will be cut by the clip path.

Comment: I tried and it actually works. But it's having an issue with different screen sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You can play with `border-bottom-right-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius` :

```css
    img {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 30%;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30%;
    }
```

```html
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

Answer (score 2):

I made some improvement to [Troyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894169/how-to-curve-the-div-from-bottom-with-image-background/43894215#43894215) to make it more similar to your example using the length and percentage of [`border-radius`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) property.

```
border-bottom-left-radius: [length] [percentage];
```

```css
img {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 25%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 25%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9A5S.jpg">
```

Comment: But it's not exactly correct, you see the both sides?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
      <style type="text/css">

      /*if you want to curve on top position*/

      #img{
        border-top-right-radius:50% 10%;
        border-top-left-radius:50% 10%;   
    }
    /*if you want to curve on bottom position*/
     /*   #img{    
        border-bottom-right-radius:50% 10%;
        border-bottom-left-radius:50% 10%
    }*/
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9A5S.jpg" height="400" width="400" id="img">



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here you go, hopefully this works fine for your, maybe you should change the % values a bit.

```css
img {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 180% 90%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 180% 90%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/600x300">
```

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the old post.Hope this will work.

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.hero-main{
   background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9A5S.jpg");
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 350px;
   width: 100%;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 100% 75%;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 100% 75%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
 <section class="hero-main">
          <div class="wrapper hero-inner text-center">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
            <h2Lorem ipsum. 
            </h2>
           
          </div>
      </section>
```